# robocopy: excluding directories

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I use robocopy to back up files. Because I need to exclude some directories, I tested the following switch first:

/xd dirs t*

It successfully excludes all directories whose name starts with t. That isn't really what I wanted though. What I really want is to exclude the directories whose name start with thunderbird\cache, such as thunderbird\cache, thunderbird\cache2, etc. So, I tried this one:

/xd dirs thunderbird\cache*

However, robocopy complains about it, saying "ERROR : Invalid Parameter #7 : "thunderbird\cache*"".

What is the syntax to use wildcard in path?

Comment: BTW, the word `dirs` itself is not a part of `/XD` parameter syntax; hence, `/xd t*` should suffice. Moreover: It appears that, unlike `/XF`, `/XD` does not allow wildcards. From `robocopy /?`: `/XF file [file]... : eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.` but `/XD dirs [dirs]... : eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.` However, I'd try `/xd:thunderbird\cache*`

Comment: I have tried both "t*" and "t". The log files are different. With "t", some thunderbird directories were still copied. With "t*", no directories whose name starts with t (two directories: thunderbird and temp) were copied. That lead me to believe that /xd does take wildcard, albeit claimed otherwise elsewhere.

Comment: The `/XD` option of `robocopy` seems to accept wildcards as long as there is no path separator `\ `in the given value; so `cache*` is accepted, but `thunderbird\cache*` is not...

Answer (score 2):

The `/XD` option of the [`robocopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) seems to accept wildcards as long as there is no path separator `\` in the given value; so `cache*` is accepted, but `thunderbird\cache*` is not.

You could work around that using the following code in your batch file:

```cmd
set "DIRS= "
for /D %%I in ("thunderbird\cache*") do call set "DIRS=%%DIRS%%"%%~I" "
robocopy "D:\source" "D:\destination" *.* /XD %DIRS%
```